# DOJO button example

Tags: dojo

Hi i am beginner in learning DOJO ...i tried the following code,but when i pressed the hello world button no alert box is shown,Kindly find the error

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Button</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js">
dojo.require("dojo.event.*");
dojo.require("dojo.widget.*");
dojo.require("dojo.widget.Button");
function hp()
{
alert("pressed");
}
function init()
{
var hellobutton=dojo.widgetById('helloButton');
}
dojo.event.connect(hellobutton,'onClick','hp');
dojo.addOnLoad(init);
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
<p align="center"><font size="6" color="#800000">Welcome to Dojo Project</font></p>
<button dojoType="Button" widgetId="helloButton" onClick="hp();">HelloWorld!</Button>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Problem lies in the fact, that you have no opening script Tag for your javascript. If you do it like this, your code works fine.

Here's a fiddle for it : http://jsfiddle.net/KWWfP/

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>

<script>
dojo.require("dojo.event.*");
dojo.require("dojo.widget.*");
dojo.require("dojo.widget.Button");

function hp(){
    alert("pressed");
}

function init(){
    var hellobutton=dojo.widgetById('helloButton');
 }

dojo.event.connect(hellobutton,'onClick','hp');
dojo.addOnLoad(init);
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
    <p align="center"><font size="6" color="#800000">Welcome to Dojo Project</font></p>
    <button dojoType="Button" widgetId="helloButton" onClick="hp();">HelloWorld!
    </button>
<br>
</body>
```

And you should have a look how you open and end your Tags - to start the button-tag with lowercase and end it with capital is not appropriate.

```
 <button></Button>
```

Regards, Miriam

Comment: No Problem - and for further informations and tutorials for dojo have a look : https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/